# Remove Duplicated from results

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a database and I'd like to show some results from it without getting duplicates

### Example

```
<?php

    $sql = "select * from my_table order by subcategory ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die($qry);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == '0') {
        echo "No subcategory";
    } else {
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $line[subcategory];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

It currently shows me all subcategories even if they are duplicated
**Question:** How i can filter the results so that it will only show a subcategory once even if it's in there 4 times.

Do I need to add something to this code to shows only without duplicated?

```
$sql ="select * from rss order by subcategory ASC";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
$sql = "select subcategory from rss group by subcategory"
```

See the manual for more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use DISTINCT in your SQL, to avoid getting duplicates back from the database, like this:

```
select distinct * from my_table order by subcategory ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from rss order by subcategory ASC
```

First of all it is a good practive to expand wildcard. List all of the columns instead of using `*`

There are two approaches on what you're trying to achieve depending on what you need:

1. `Select distinct column1,column2 from rss order by subcategory desc`
2. `select max(column1), max(column2), subcategory from rss order by subcategory desc group by subcategory`

Answer (score 3):

Look into `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

use `continue;` keyword  and check for duplicates in your while loop

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from my_table order by subcategory ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($qry);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == '0') {
    echo "No subcategory";
} else {
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($dupes[$line['subcategory']])
            continue;
        $dupes[$line['subcategory']]++;


        echo $line['subcategory'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

or just use `distinct`

```
$sql ="select distinct * from rss order by subcategory ASC";
```

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at [`array_unique()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Use it to remove all duplicates from the array.